# deferredCurrentActivation fatal exception

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-mojave

I'm suddenly seeing the following on Crashlytics for a macOS app, and this seems to happen only on macOS 10.14. I have no idea what this is. What's `deferredCurrentActivation` and how do I avoid this? Anyone else seen this?

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
deferredCurrentActivation already set when we got another deferred activate event
```